# Do I need whom in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, whom

"One of the benefits of this is that it will eliminate gym anxiety if you have any because you are with someone **whom** you trust."

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "with someone whom" and "with whom" are not very closely related. In a phrase like "with someone who is trustworthy", it is not possible to replace *who* with *whom.*

Comment: @sumelic Nor does the question this is marked a duplicate of say that you should. Your example changes the construction of the sentence by introducing a verb into the phrase.

Comment: @JasonBassford: "with someone whom you trust" and "with someone who is trustworthy" both have relative clauses with verbs; "whom" is the object of the verb in the first and the subject of the verb in the second. In both cases, the use of "who" vs. "whom" is dictated by the pronoun's relationship to the verb in the relative clause. In "The person with whom I'm doing the project", the use of "whom" is dictated by its relationship to the preposition "with".

Answer (score 1):

In this sentence, *whom* can be removed without changing the meaning of the sentence.